# If $f(x)=x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x...\infty}}}(x\gt0)$ then $f'(5)$ is not less than... $1/3/4/5/10?$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

> If $f(x)=x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x...\infty}}}(x\gt0)$ then $f'(5)$ is not less than... $1/3/4/5/10?$ (more than one option can be correct)

Let $y=f(x)\implies y=x\sqrt y\implies y^2=x^2y\implies y=x^2\implies y'=2x\implies f'(5)=10$

So, my answer is $f'(5)$ is not less than all the given options i.e. $1,3,4,5,10$. Is this correct?

I am doubting because it is somehow feeling weird. Also, is $y$ really $x^2$? From the given statement, it's difficult to tell. Is it possible that $f'(5)$ is not exactly $10$? Rather it's slightly less than $10$? I don't know.

Comment: $f(x)=x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x...\infty}}}$ means nothing unless you define it.

Comment: $y^2 = x^2 y \implies y = x^2$ only if $y\ne 0$. And you'll have trouble trying to prove that unless you define in a precise manner what $x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x…\infty}}}$ means.

Comment: Hi. I have posted the question verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what $f(x)=x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x...\infty}}}$ means. If it means $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x \sqrt{x\sqrt{x\ldots\sqrt{x}}}$ ($n $ roots), then your answer is correct. We need to prove that limit exists, but it does, as we can even explicitly rewrite the expression under limit as $x^{2 - 2^{-n}}$.

However, why it seems "natural" to define $f$ this way, it's hard to argue what stops us from saying, for example $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\ldots{\sqrt{0}}}}$ and then we will have $f(x) \equiv 0$.